# I have been banned to ask questions

Tags: support

I have been banned to ask questions for no apparent reason: I only have 5 questions there and all of them have upvotes and answers, none of the questions are flagged to be closed either.

Can anyone please tell me what happened and how to ask questions again? https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/40809/luis-valencia

The answer proposed does not help, why:

I have up votes, too many views on my questions, and even favorited many times
I have no deleted questions according to my profile
Last question was asked in 2016 and according to the website,  and it says that after 6 months I could ask again to see if the question is welcomed positvely in the community.

I have had a good reputation in other SO websites with thousands of votes and I am very surprised because I never received any kind of warning whatsoever.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have asked 10 questions on Software Engineering. Of these 10 questions, 6 are deleted questions. In addition to being deleted, they are all negatively scored. Your total score across all 10 questions asked is -13 (-20 from deleted questions, +7 from non-deleted questions).

Because of the low net score and number of deleted questions, an automatic question block was triggered.

See: [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

Comment: ok and how do I improve this to be able to ask again?

Comment: @LuisValencia I added a link to the Meta Stack Exchange post about the automated question/answer block. The canonical information on getting out of the block lives there.

Comment: I am sorry but this is not clear, I have to edit the current questions, only 4, and they are already answered, so editing this I doubt will have an impact,  I cannt undeleted posts to make them better, also it says: If you're unable to improve your existing questions, you'll get the chance to ask one new one 6 months after your last question. If that question is positively received, you may be able to continue asking questions; if not, then the ban will be reinstated. I think my last questionw as more than 6 months ago, right?

Comment: related: [Show all of my question/answers to me even if they are deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2645/165773). 800+ upvotes, 22 answers and 19 bounties from 15 users (including multiple moderators)... but apparently forcing users to bring their old dirty laundry to meta is considered a better approach than letting them see their deleted posts for last 600 days instead of last 60

Comment: @LuisValencia If you have specific questions, you should go to Meta Stack Exchange. The algorithms used in question blocks are not known beyond SE staff and they cannot be overridden by moderators. What is in that question I linked to is supposed to be the most recent, up-to-date information available. That's all I can tell you.

Comment: when was my last question asked?, I asked this already on META SE and they told me to ask it here.

Comment: @LuisValencia Your last question was asked on April 3. It was deleted and scored at -2. It has not yet been 6 months since this question was asked.

Comment: @LuisValencia a less known option you can try it to delete your account at this site, then create it again and restart at asking rate of 1 question a week (if you're interested I strongly recommend to [refer here for more detailed explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234610/165773)). In your case it will likely mean loss of 66 rep points (since 100 points of association bonus will recover) and disassociation with all your current posts, both visible and deleted ones